# How to display this array data along with its respective page number?

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I've this pagination code in **pagination.php** file which I've included in the main index file.

```
<?php

$allItems = [];

for ($i=0; $i<25; $i++) 
{
    $allItems[] = $i;
}

$totalrows = count($allItems);
$perpage = 10;

$totalpages = ceil($totalrows / $perpage); // total number of pages

if ($totalpages < 1)
{
    $totalpages = 1;
}

$page = 1;
if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
}

if ($page < 1)
{ 
    $page = 1; 
} 
elseif ($page > $totalpages)
{ 
    $page = $totalpages; // set page to totalpages page number
}

$offset = ($page - 1) * $perpage;

if ($offset < 0)
{
    $offset = 0;
}

$allItems = array_slice($allItems, $offset, $perpage);

$pagination = "";

if ($totalpages != 1)
{
    $pagination .= '<ul class="pagination">';
    // first and previous link
    if ($page > 1) 
    {
        $previous = $page - 1;
        $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=1" class="btn btn-default">First</a></li>'; // goto first page
        $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . $previous . '" class="btn btn-default">Previous</a></li>';
    }

    // display page numbers
    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $totalpages; $i++)
    {
        if ($i != $page)
        {
            $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $i .'" class="btn btn-default">'.$i.'</a></li> ';
        }
        else
        {
            $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">' . $i . '</button></li>';
        }
    }

    // last and next link
    if ($page != $totalpages)
    {
        $next = $page + 1;
        $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $next . '" class="btn btn-default">Next</a></li>';
        $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $totalpages . '" class="btn btn-default">Last</a></li>'; // goto totalpages page
    }
    $pagination .= '</ul>'; // close ul
}
```

Currently it only display the page numbers and First/Last, Next/Previous links, but not the actual array data when I goto the respective page.

Please help me with this, how can I display this array data in the following code.

**index.php** file

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php
                    // <td> how should I display here in table </td>    
                ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add those `$allItems` value to any loop like `foreach`

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $str = "";
                foreach ($allItems as $key => $value) {
                    $str .= "<tr><td>$value</td></tr>";
                }
                echo $str;
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh that was the trick I'm missing. It's perfect now.Thanks a lot @C2486.